# Where can I find VIDLE?

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, vpython

I am new to Python. I was trying to learn Python using Anaconda Python 2.7 and its Spyder app. I'd like to use Vpython to create 3D objects. So I installed vpython using

conda install -c mwcraig vpython

which is what they suggested and it worked. I just couldn't find the VIDLE shortcut anywhere. Can anyone show me the direction?

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) Why do you need VIDLE if you plan to use Spyder? I say it because they are more or less the same kind of program :-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! You are probably right. But I am not a professional programmer. So I'd like things to be simple enough to use. :) VIDLE has a nice interface that you can especially use to manipulate 3D graphs. I am not sure whether Spyder can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well if anyone else is wondering, I went to https://vpython.org/contents/download_windows.html

Then followed the instructions under the section labeled "Windows downloads for VPython 6"